# Issue with Unity.Tasks in the ios-firebase unity plugin

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest IOS-Unity plugin and I keep getting this compilation error:

> Assets/Scripts/Analytics.cs(38,16): error CS0012: The type
>   `System.Threading.Tasks.Task' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly`Unity.Tasks,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

It's worth noting that before this error it complained about a duplicate UnityCompat.dll file (defined in both Firebase/Plugins and Parse/Plugins -- I ended up removing the one in the Parse directory, but I have tried the opposite as well).

Any pointers would be great. Also worth noting that this happened after removing obsolete files from the PlayServices plugin when prompted.

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question (from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/2w1Lk62VIcg)

Parse/Plugins/Unity.Tasks needs to the enabled for compilation (using Unity's Inspector)
Parse/Plugins/Unity.Compat needs to be disabled

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by following the documentation :
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#set_up_environment)

Assets > Play Services Resolver > Version Handler > Update to enable the correct DLLs for your project.